How to reset mongodb root password in a replica set configuration?
I was following some how-to, but I always get the following erro. How to reset the admin (root role) password when running a replica set in mongodb?
The steps was:
Stop all mongodb instances in the replica set
start one mongo instance as
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --port 27017 --bind_ip localhost
--replSet rs0 --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Connect to the instance and change the password:
use admin
db.updateUser("root", {pwd: "test123"});

But I always get the error
admin> db.updateUser("root", {pwd: "test123"});
MongoServerError[NotWritablePrimary]: not primary


The "official" way is like this:

Start all replica set members.
Start one member with option --transitionToAuth
Connect to this member directly. If needed, run rs.stepDown() to make it the PRIMARY
Change the root password
Restart the member with default config.

Be aware, while member runs with --transitionToAuth everybody may connect without credentials and gain full root privileges.
However, there is a much simpler way of doing it. Simply use the internal credentials, i.e. the security.keyFile to connect. Would be this one:
mongosh "mongodb://localhost:27017/?authSource=local" -u __system -p "$(tr -d '\011-\015\040' < path-to-keyfile)"

tr -d '\011-\015\040' is only needed if your keyfile contains any new-line characters.
If you use x.509 certificates for internal membership authentication, it works in the same way. Simply use the server net.tls.clusterFile to connect.

Thanks, the two methods has worked like a charm!
